# RTK Query - Select from cached list or else fetch item

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

I have 2 endpoints. One for fetching a list of users (with all related data), and one for just fetching one of them. I would like to be able to share cached data between these 2 endpoints.

I need this because I have 2 pages, one with the list of users, and one that displays the data of a given user where I would like to be able to reuse the data that's already in the list, or in case it's not there, just fetch the data I need.

Here are the two endpoints:

```
getTeachers: builder.query({
      query: ({ page, orderBy, orderDirection }) =>
        buildQueryWithParams('teachers', {
          limit: bigPaginationLimit,
          offset: (page - 1) * bigPaginationLimit,
          orderBy,
          orderDirection
        }),
      providesTags: (res) =>
        res.list
          ? [
              res.list.map((item) => ({
                type: 'teacher',
                id: item.id
              }))
            ]
          : [{ type: 'teacher', id: 'list' }]
getTeacher: builder.query({
      query: (id) => `/teachers/${id}`,
      providesTags: (res, error, id) => [{ type: 'teacher', id }]
    })
```

I was hoping that giving the objects the same tags would make it so that they share a cache, but I've since found out that RTK Query doesn't use the tags for the cache.

Is there any way of sharing caches between these two endpoints?
If not, how could I go about using the data from the list if it's there, and otherwise just fetching the single user.

Answer (score 0):

1. Perform a check on the data returned from `getTeachers` for the
   given user's existence using some array function(Like `filter` or`find`). This step assumes you know the list of given user's you would be checking for.
2. If it exists then send a query function prop as null to the child
   component that would be using that id's data and use the filtered data for that user returned from `getTeachers` as source.
3. if not send the `getTeacher` as a prop along with `userId`, the query function which would run
   when the child component loads.

Here is an example of same component running different queries based on two different scenarios:
https://github.com/marciamoss/1stop_rtk/blob/main/src/components/MusicPage/MusicPage.js
calls a child component `<MusicList>` with two different query functions (line 41 and line 85).
In your case you just make the query function null for one of the scenario and initialize data to `getTeachers` filtered data for that user.

Comment: Unfortunate that this has to be done manually, it seems like a simple use case.